# Simulating video games without rendering for training models (such as NEAT)

Tags: game, simulation, game-development, machine-learning, neural-network

A bit of a duplicate of [my question on AI.SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/35785/4709) (I've been told this is the place to ask):

YouTube was recently suggesting to me videos of people training NEAT neural networks for video games. I've noticed that often the training process was quite slow (for example in [this Trackmania example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a8Bo2DHrrow)).

Is there a way/a tool to easily simulate video games, without actually rendering the pixels on screen and making the training much quicker? (it sounds reasonable for such tool to exist since OpenAI was able to train their "Dota 2" model this way)

Comment: Welcome! I don't know the answer to your question, but one thought I have is to use as low of a resolution as possible.  Adjusting the frame rate may be beneficial as well.  Years ago, I needed to create neural network training data for a simulation that was graphically intensive.  My solution was to train the neural net on the intermediate data on which the graphical output was generated.  It was long enough ago that I don't recall all the details, but IIRC, this allowed me to decrease the neural net training time by a factor of over 10K.